# Finding a string with double quotes

Tags: c#, string, indexof

I want this line of code to work-

```
int start = s.IndexOf(""_type": "Person""name": "");
```

But clearly the double quotes are messing up the search... Any ideas about how to get this working?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here.  Can you show which strings you want to search on/in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take two approaches to this.

The first is by using a [string-literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and escaping double-quotes with another double quote:

```
string s = @"This is a ""quoted"" string.";
s.IndexOf(@"a ""quoted"" string");
```

The other is to escape the double-quotes with a backslash:

```
string s = "This is a \"quoted\" string.";
s.IndexOf("a \"quoted\" string");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a double-quote in a string, one way is to escape it with a backslash. `\`

```
string myString = "This is a string \" with a double quote";
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is escape the string? Try this:

```
   int start = s.IndexOf(@"this ""word"" is escaped");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to run IndexOf() on the entire string, including the quotes inside? All you have to do is use both types of quotes: ' ' and " ". As long as you use one to designate the main string and the other to designate sub-strings, it should work, i.e. something like: `s.IndexOf(' "_type": "Person""name": " ');`